# Git bash opens in window outside of emacs

Tags: shell, git, shell-command, bash

When running Emacs on Windows 10, I am able to launch git bash from within Emacs using the information given [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/22049/git-bash-in-emacs-on-windows/22057#), [here](https://tangjunjie.wordpress.com/2015/10/20/windows-emacs-git-bash-and-shell-command/), or [here](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/running-shells-in-emacs-overview). For example, I can just add these two lines to my .emacs:

```
(setq explicit-shell-file-name "C:/Program Files/Git/git-bash.exe")
(setq explicit-bash.exe-args '("--login" "-i"))
```

Then, `M-x shell` opens a git bash.

However, git bash always opens in its own window, not as a buffer within Emacs. This is undesirable as it breaks my workflow within emacs. It also, apparently, isn't what usually happens, judging by the experience of other users.

Any ideas on how I can get git bash to open up within emacs? Thanks!

Comment: Check your sources again, they are not using the same file as you are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using

```
(setq shell-file-name "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe")
```

`git-bash.exe` does seem to want to open up an external window. `bash.exe` seems to start the git bash shell in the emacs window.

Comment: I recommend you use `/` instead of ``\\`` in your filenames.  It'll work just as well but without the pain of having to double them all.