# Emacs opens gitbash in new system window

Tags: microsoft-windows, git, ansi-term, bash

I've try to follow this question and sulution [Git Bash in emacs on Windows](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/22049/git-bash-in-emacs-on-windows) I have this function:

```
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
(defun git-bash ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((explicit-shell-file-name "C:/Users/jankiewj/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/git-bash.exe")
        (explicit-bash.exe-args '("--login" "-i")))
    (call-interactively 'shell)))
```

but when I execute this function, git bash is created in new system window instead of Emacs window. So I don't even get the same error as OP.

I've also tried to run ansi-term but got error:

```
apply: Spawning child process: Invalid argument
```

How can I make git bash work inside Emacs window on MS Windows?

Comment: You could try running something like http://www.msys2.org/ and running both emacs and git (and bash) inside of it. It should make spawning shells easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the answer provided in: [Git Bash in emacs on Windows](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/22049/git-bash-in-emacs-on-windows?newreg=8b3f88c47e30435b936261553f5143f0)

Most importantly, make sure that you are using `bin/bash.exe` rather than `git-bash.exe`.

You're good to use the `defun` apprach that you have in your question to make it work with an emacs command other than `M-x shell` (`M-x git-bash` in your case).

If you just want to change the shell that `M-x shell` uses, then you only need your `init.el` to have something like:

```
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
(setq explicit-shell-file-name "C:/Program Files/Git/bin/bash.exe")
(setq explicit-bash.exe-args '("--login" "-i"))
```

The last important bit is that your `~/.bashrc` (or other bash config file) should define a simpler [`PS1`](https://www.linuxnix.com/linuxunix-shell-ps1-prompt-explained-in-detail/) for your prompt. This was the example given in the other answer:

```
if [ -n "$INSIDE_EMACS" ]; then
    export PS1='\[\033[32m\]\u@\h \[\033[33m\]\w\[\033[36m\]`__git_ps1`\[\033[0m\]\n$ '
fi
```

Comment: I don't get the error anymore but I can't interact with the terminal, enter is not sent to terminal. I probably need to ask another question.

Comment: I've asked here [Enter not sent to bash in shell buffer on Windows](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/46147/10438)