# How to find a file recursively on Microsoft Windows with findutils (gnu find) installed?

Tags: helm, microsoft-windows, find

I'm trying to find file recursively from `default-directory` with `helm-find` (`C-x c /`). It works out of box in linux.

I tried setting `find-program` like (I have git bash installed)

```
(setq find-program "c:/Program\ Files/Git/usr/bin/find.exe")
```

It didn't work.

Then I tried installing findutils (gnu find) from chocolatey and then tried.

```
(setq find-program "C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/find.exe")
```

This did not work either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Find works after setting the shell to git bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `helm-find` uses `find-cmd.el`. This `find-cmd` function generates a GNU find style command that runs without issues on bash, but fails to run on powershell. The default shell in Emacs is PowerShell. If you set your default shell to Git bash (You can follow the steps in this [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/22049/git-bash-in-emacs-on-windows) to do that.), then it works.

Some Elisp script to do that:

```lisp
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
(setq shell-file-name "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe")
(setq explicit-bash.exe-args '("--login" "-i"))
(setq find-program "C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/find.exe")
```